# Spring MVC -- Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

I am a newbie at Spring 3.1 MVC, and I need some help.  I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what.  And yes, I've done Google searches for tutorials.  I am simply trying to call a JSP for the first time, and I get this.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'comment' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(GuestBook_jsp.java:271)
    at org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(GuestBook_jsp.java:216)
    at org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspService(GuestBook_jsp.java:127)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the form in my JSP.

```
<form:form method="post" action="GuestBook.jsp" modelAttribute="comment">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="comment.name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="comment.name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="comment.message">Message</form:label></td>
            <td><form:textarea path="comment.message" rows="10" cols="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit comment" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Here is my controller.

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.dao.CommentDAO;
import com.model.Comment;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/GuestBook.jsp")
@SessionAttributes("comment")
public class CommentController {
    Comment comment;

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addComment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addComment(@ModelAttribute("comment") Comment comment, BindingResult result) {
        CommentDAO commentDAO = new CommentDAO();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
        comment.setDate(date);

        if (commentDAO.writeComment(comment) == true) {
            return "redirect:GuestBook.jsp";
        }

        return "redirect:Oops.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showComments")
    public ModelAndView showComments() {
        return new ModelAndView("comment", "command", new Comment());
    }
}
```

Here is ghs1986-servlet.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="comment" class="com.model.Comment" />

    <bean name="/GuestBook.jsp" class="com.controller.CommentController">
        <property name="comment" ref="comment" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must add bean to a model in controller method that is responsible for feeding data into form.

Just add model as method param and then in body, add empty comment bean to a model

Comment: Which method, exactly, gets the model as a parameter?

Comment: not quite sure... Do you present form on showComments? What you did there seems to me suspicious, not telling that is wrong and not same thing I am talking about... But just try to get Model bean inside the method and add new Comment bean to model.

Comment: Btw, any controller method can have Model, Session, Request etc. as additional param